Circuit diagram for collecting electrocardiogram and electromyographic signals using ADS1292R 24-Bit ADC / ECG Front End
I want to use ADS1292R (2-Channel 24-Bit ADC With Integrated Respiration Impedance and ECG Front End) to collect both electrocardiogram (ECG) and electromyographic (EMG) signals, but not at the same time. The electrode wires are the same, and by switching, when collecting ECG, EMG is not collected, and when collecting EMG, ECG is not collected. Do you have a corresponding circuit plan?

You need to define design specs. And tolerances. No rush.

Consider using a multiple pole relay

To help get an answer can you [edit] the question to include (a) Links to the datasheets for the ECG and EMG (b) A schematic or table of how many signals are required to be switched
